# Area of a region between two curves definition

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

My textbook defines the area of a region between two curves as:

> If $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ and $g(x) \le f(x)$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$, then the area of the region bounded by the graphs of $f$ and $g$ and the vertical lines $x = a$ and $x = b$ is
>      $A = \int_a^b [f(x)-g(x)] \, dx$

My question is what is the meaning of $g(x) \le f(x)$? Is it saying that the height of $g(x)$ is less than the height of $f(x)$ or is talking about the function themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to remember is that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are numbers (for a fixed value of $x$), so saying that $g(x) \le f(x)$ for $x \in [a,b]$ simply means that for any value of $x$ in that interval, the number $g(x)$ is less than or equal to $f(x)$.

In terms of the graphs, it means that the graph of $g(x)$ does not go above  the graph of $f(x)$.

Comment: Makes sense, but can that be solved algebraically and if so how?

Comment: It can be solved algebraically in some cases - if you know the algebraic definitions of $g(x)$ and $f(x)$.

Comment: If the definition is written in that fashion ("upper curve minus lower curve"), it automatically gets the signs right (keeping the area between the curves positive) regardless of whether either function becomes negative (crossing below the x-axis) without having to mess about with absolute value brackets...